# Problema ao executar componentes principais

Tags: c++, opencv

Olá, estou executando um algoritmo para classificação de objetos em uma imagem. No atual momento eu preciso determinar as coordenadas do centro do obejto para calcular o diâmetro e aplicar compacidade.

A parte do código que faz isso é:

```
cv::Point encontraCentros(const vector<Point> contornos, const vector<Point> &centros)
{

    //Faz um buffer usado pela PCA
    int tam = static_cast<int>(contornos.size());
    Mat dados_contornos = Mat(tam, 2, CV_64FC1);

    for (int i = 0; i < dados_contornos.rows; ++i)
    {
        dados_contornos.at<double>(i, 0) = contornos[i].x;
        dados_contornos.at<double>(i, 1) = contornos[i].y;
    }

    //Executa PCA
    PCA pca_analysis(dados_contornos, Mat(), PCA::DATA_AS_ROW);

    //Armazena o centro do objeto
    Point centros = Point(static_cast<int>(pca_analysis.mean.at<double>(0, 0)),
                          static_cast<int>(pca_analysis.mean.at<double>(0, 1)));

    return centros;
}
```

Porém o codeBlocks dá o seguinte erro:

> declaration of 'cv::Point centros' shadows a parameter

Alguém tem ideia do que possa ser isso?

Comment: Já existe um parâmetro chamado `centros` dentro da função, e você está a declarar uma nova variável com o mesmo nome.